# Method appears to be called twice

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application where users will enter accommodation details including the cost per night and then select the appropriate currency from a drop down.  I am then using fixer.io to show the cost in both the currency it was entered in as well as converted to the user's default currency.

The cost is stored in the database as an integer.  I have methods `convertToInteger` and `convertFromInteger` that take the currency, look up how many subunits there are and do the appropriate math.

There is also a `formatCurrency` method to format according to currency.  And a `convertBetweenCurrency` method for the actual conversion.

The `convertFromInteger` method is called inside the `formatCurrency` method.

The `$cost_per_night_entered` works fine and displays the correct amount and formatting.  However, the `$cost_per_night_user` appears to be converted from Integer twice - it is always out by that unit.  So, $148 is displayed as $1.48.

I've tried using Laravel's `fresh()` and `refresh()` to no avail.  Is this related to 'nesting' the calls together?  I don't think I've done something dumb like call it twice - but fresh eyes may prove otherwise :)

Controller `show` method:

```
$cost_per_night_entered = formatCurrency($accommodation->cost_per_night, $accommodation->currency, getLocale($accommodation->country));

$cost_per_night_user = formatCurrency(convertBetweenCurrency($accommodation->cost_per_night, $accommodation->currency, Auth::user()->currency), Auth::user()->currency, request()->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'));
```

Model methods:

```
function formatCurrency($amount, $currency_code, $locale)
{
$value = intval(convertFromInteger($amount, $currency_code));

$money = new Money\Money($value, new Money\Currency($currency_code));
$currencies = new Money\Currencies\ISOCurrencies();

$numberFormatter = new \NumberFormatter($locale, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$moneyFormatter = new Money\Formatter\IntlMoneyFormatter($numberFormatter, $currencies);

return $moneyFormatter->format($money);
}



function convertBetweenCurrency($amount, $from_currency, $to_currency)
{
$endpoint = 'convert';
$access_key = 'xxx';

// initialize CURL:
$ch = curl_init('http://data.fixer.io/api/'.$endpoint.'? access_key='.$access_key.'&from='.$from_currency.'&to='.$to_currency.'&amount='.$amount.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// get the JSON data:
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Decode JSON response:
$conversionResult = json_decode($json, true);

// access the conversion result
return intval($conversionResult['result']);
}



function convertFromInteger($amount, $currency_code)
{
$currencies = PragmaRX\Countries\Package\Countries::currencies();

$currency = $currencies->where('iso.code', $currency_code)->toArray();

return $amount / (1 / $currency[$currency_code]['units']['minor']['majorValue']);
}
```

Comment: This line seems rather odd: `$value = intval(convertFromInteger($amount, $currency_code));`. You're casting to integer a float you got from an integer?

Comment: Thank you @El_Vanja That seems to be the issue. Removing this line works for a few different currencies I’ve tried, but I’m still having an issue with the Icelandic Krona. I just happened to pick that currency to use but now realise the issue is specific to it. (That was the reason for the weird line you pointed out.). Thanks for heading me in the right direction :)